# Identify a blank line in a text area

Tags: php

I am trying to identify a blank lines in a string. Below is my attempt in PHP:

```
<?php 
$alldevs = $_POST['devs'];
$devices = explode("\n", $alldevs);

foreach($devices as $device) {
    if(!empty($device)){
        echo $device;
    } else {
        echo "end of value";
    }
}
?>
```

When I input the following:

```
1
2
3

4
```

I get this output:

```
1
2
3

4
```

But what it should be outputting is this:

```
1
2
3
end of value
end of value
4
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should remove some blank lines from your `edit question` text area

Comment: "Is this correct syntax ?" -> Have you tried before?

Comment: I'll teach you a little secret: the `Tab` key on keyboard is not for decoration only.

Comment: @nic - is that really all you could see that needed fixing when you edited this post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They probably contain a `\r` (which is posted on new lines in text areas for some browsers/OS'es), a space or a tab character. You can get rid of these by using the [`trim()`](http://www.php.net/trim) command:

```
<?php 
    $alldevs = $_POST['devs'];
    $devices = explode("\n", $alldevs);
    foreach ($devices as $device) {
        $device = trim($device); //Trim that string!
        if(!empty($device)) 
        {
            echo $device;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "end of value";
        }
    }
?>
```

**Oh, and PLEASE indent your code for your own and everybody elses sake**.

Alternatively, split up your string by using regex:

```
$devices = preg_split("/(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/", $alldevs);
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but using `trim()` would cause you to lose potentially important formatting, throwing the baby out with the bathwater, so to speak.  Your `preg_split()` solution is much better, though I question the need for `\n\r` replacement.  As far as I know, Windows = `\r\n`, Mac = `\r`, and *nix = `\n`.  Not sure what would be using the (broken) `\n\r` EOL.

Comment: [*LF+CR: Acorn BBC and RISC OS spooled text output.*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). So yes, very outdated/unused systems, but they *do* exist.

Comment: Very interesting.  To be Unicode compliant, I guess you'll need to add a whole slew of other sequences.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

This should give you what you want:

```
if( trim($device) !== '' )
{
    echo $device."<br>";
}
else
{
    echo "end of value"."<br>";
}
```

Outputs:

```
1 
2 
3 
end of value
4
```

Comment: This is the one that I liked best (+1)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is with `\r\n`

Use this code

```
$alldevs = str_replace("\r", '', $alldevs);
```

Then explode it, and also use `trim` for clean spaces

```
$alldevs = trim($alldevs);
```

Answer (score 1):

first, please read [dealing with line endings](http://www.f15ijp.com/2010/07/different-lineendings-on-diffrent-os/) and [wikipedia newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

second, you are using string explode when you should use a function like [preg_match_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

code should look something like this (mind the bad regex please):

```
<?php
$string = $_POST['devs'];
preg_match_all('%^([^\n\r]*)[\n\r]?$%im', $string, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
    if($match) {
        var_dump($match);
    } else {
        echo 'empty line' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

adjust this code to fit your needs, i left a var_dump there so you could see the string length.

Answer (score 0):

Add a check for a string with more than 0 characters,

`if(!empty($device) && strlen($device)>0)` {

I would also try a use case with `\r\n` on your line-breaks, you'll run into that as well.

Comment: I think `$device !== ''` or `is_null` is better

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$devices = preg_replace('/^\s*$/','end of value',explode("\n",$alldevs));
foreach($devices as $device) {
    echo $device, "\n";
}
```